# switch Dell 3424P SSH enable mode failed

Tags: ssh, switch, dell

I have a Dell 3424P switch and I want to administrate it only by console and ssh.

I can connect to the switch in ssh but I can't elevate my privileges. When I type `enable`, it responds :

> Cannot authenticate user due to:
>   bad/missing configuration, inaccessible server, user low privileges.
>   Please reconfigure or use Password Recovery.

I've tried many solutions but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to any reason. If password recovery is not working - you should reset switch to factory settings. If resetting switch is not working - it may have its flash failed, like becoming non-writable.